# Ctrl-c Not stopping Docker Container from running in Git Bash

Tags: docker, git-bash

I am trying to stop Docker container using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in Git Bash but it is not:
[image]

I tried to Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for 5 sec as it suggested in a solution on how to stop tomcat in Git Bash if
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
docker run redis
```

the container isn't running interactively and with an attached TTY, so your ctrl-c never reaches the container. If you do

```
docker run -it redis
```

ctrl-c will be sent to redis and the container will stop.